# Would travelling to Moscow by other means than the intended cause legal trouble?

Tags: visas, trains, international-travel, russia

I was going to travel to Moscow today by car (followed by a trip to Kazakhstan and Kyrgyzstan before returning to Russia via Siberia. I have a visa valid for two entries. However, we're currently stuck in Rezekne, Latvia, waiting for some paperwork to finish. This may or may not be finished tomorrow, and I would like to travel on as soon as possible. I see that there is a train from Rezekne to Moscow leaving tonight.

Can I take the train, instead of going by car? Would this cause me any trouble later during the trip, especially regarding visa issues?

Comment: It will not be a problem as long as your 'invitation' still sync's up with your travel dates.

Comment: Gayot: sorry for the late reply. Will you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OK, it's a very brief answer; but it contains the necessary details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Can I take the train, instead of going by car? Would this cause me any trouble later during the trip, especially regarding visa issues?***

It will not be a problem as long as your 'invitation' still sync's up with your travel dates.  Also, it will not prevent you from getting visas in the future.